# Jongo create Ref and no embedded object

Tags: jongo

What is the best way to set an dbRef in entity? I would not save a relation as embedded object in a collection for example.

```
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public String id;

    private List<Article> articles;
}

public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public String id;

    private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jongo save relations as embedded document.

If you realy want's dbRef instead, you'll have to deal it by yourself.

```
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public String id;

     // _id of articles
     private List<String> articles;
}
```

When you'll save an Order, you'll have to save `Articles`, then update your `Order`.